# How to create 100% Stacked Bar Chart with 2 sets of Groups using 4 columns (Timeseries)

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to create a 100% Stacked Bar Chart with 2 groups using 4 columns in my dataset to be displayed on a timeseries. I'm currently having challenges putting the 2 groups side by side and ordering (small % above the larger % below) the stack for each date using Plotly in R. As shown on the attached. Currently it is stack-up all columns for  every time period together causing a 200%. Any Idea on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
[4 Columns 100% Stacked Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTPoS.png)

Comment: Dear Ola, welcome to stack. Please, when asking a question, try to provide a minimal working example (see [mcve]), so that we can reproduce your problem and that the answer can be reproduced by others

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.